# Web application as a client for web service

Tags: web-services, web-applications

I am new to Web development. And hence, if the question is dumb, please be polite. For creating my application, I had to take a decision of whether writing a web service or a web application. After searching a few questions in stackoverflow, I came to know that, web service is something which doesn't involve human interaction. And web application is what human uses ( the UI/web page kind of stuffs ).

But lately, I saw gmail is a web service ( email service ). But I was confused from here on, because, gmail provides a UI, and human interactions do occur. And from there on, I got confused again.

So what I figured out from this is, gmail website is like a web application for users to use directly. The web application in turn uses the web service provided by Google for email. Is my understanding right? So can a web application be a client for web service?

If I am wrong somewhere, please do correct me. I hope to be clear after someone throws light on this with some good example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Web services can involve human interaction it does not need to but it definitely can thus it is more flexible than a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite right. Basically a Web Service has several endpoints over HTTP (normally) that provides data (generally in JSON or XML) and are meant to be consumed by Web Clients. Sometimes the are also called Web API's (Application Program Interface).

A Web Application is quite similar to a Web Service but it provides an interface where the user can interact with. Usually Web Applications are consumers of Web Services or Web APIs.

Following your example, Google email is could be considered as both, a Web Service and a Web Application. It is a Web Service because it provides a set of HTTP endpoints that works independently of its Web UI Application (GMail). In fact, you can find third party Web Apps that interact with the Google email Web API.

This concept is very important when designing Web Solutions. Ideally you want to design and implement a good Web API, usually a RESTful Service (in JSON/XML). Then you or others will be able to implement different types of applications (Web, Mobile, etc.) because of this API.

Comment: So does it mean that, even if I have a simple web page to access a web service, then is that a web application? So what is the difference between a web page and a web application? I am sorry if the question is too naive. I just wanted to be clear with the stuffs, as I am going to get involved in web development.

Comment: Technically a Web Page is just a page of your Web Application. An App or Site usually is composed by several Pages (home, about, contact, etc.), is not it? So is just that, do not worry to much about the names.

Comment: @shar your understanding is correct. you can consider webservice as a platform and language independent way to communicate between any computer application or web application. for example gmail UI or webpage (client) exchange data with google server using webservices. So in my opinion, gmail can be considered as webapplication as it implements the functionality of communicating with server via internet or web. webapplication<-->webservice<-->webserver.